# Package not found error when importing file into @Configuration class in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, aws-ssm

In my Spring application, I have a class with a @PostConstruct method that gets the values of a few parameters from Amazon SSM.

I also have a @Configuration class called DataSourceConfig where I set the database information. This class has an @autowired object from the first class so I can access the values from SSM and set them in DataSourceConfig. Because of that, I need to import the first class into the DataSourceConfig class.

When I run the project locally, it works fine, but when I run the CI pipeline, that import throws the error "package does not exist".

Why does this happen only during the pipeline, and what could be the solution?

ps: The pipeline was running with no issues before I imported this class into DataSourceConfig.